# Objective-C declaring class properties

Tags: objective-c, properties, int, setter

I'm a complete newbie to Objective-C so bear with me :-).  I'm defining a class for a record structure I want to store in a `NSMutableArray`.  Code is as follows:

```
@interface CustSuppListItem : NSObject
{
    NSString *acCode;
    NSString *acCompany;
    NSString *acContact;
    double osBalBase;
    int acAccStatus;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy, readwrite) NSString *acCode;
@property (nonatomic, copy, readwrite) NSString *acCompany;
@property (nonatomic, copy, readwrite) NSString *acContact;
@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) double osBalBase;
@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) int acAccStatus;

@end

@implementation CustSuppListItem

@synthesize acCode, acCompany, acContact, osBalBase, acAccStatus;

@end
```

When using the class in my project, the setter methods appear in the Intellisense, other than the `acAccStatus` property which seems to have not been given a setter method. I can however see it using dot notation: `object.acAccStatus`.

Is there something special about int properties that mean they are not given getter/setter methods?  Or have I defined the property incorrectly?

Comment: - [CustSuppListItem setAcAccStatus:] works fine here... Using Xcode 4.2

Comment: `int` and `double` are no objects, values are simply assigned, no setter/getter needed. Do you really need the property `copy` when putting objects into a NSMutableArray? `retain` (or `strong` if you're using ARC) should be sufficient.

Comment: by the way, `readwrite` is unnecessary here. and you can use properties without defining ivars for them, if you're targeting iOS or 64-bit Macs.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I realise I've specified more attributes for the properties than I need, it just helps me remember what options are available while I'm still learning.  Apologies - I've sussed it now, I just had a typo error in the code.
As for the 'copy' attribute - I read several posts saying this was how you should declare any properties of type NSString - is this not the case?

Comment: Yes, the general convention is that NSString properties should be copied in case the actual object it refers to is an NSMutableString, which could be modified without you knowing and leave the object in some kind of inconsistent state. Also, just because an instance variable is a primitive type (e.g. int or double) doesn't necessarily mean that you shouldn't use accessors/properties for them.

Comment: `copy` is fine for NSString - lots of posts on here about that. Admirable to be adding readwrite to help you remember. And there is a getter and setter synthesised for int and double. Presumably just your code completion is messed up?

Comment: Thanks Adam/Matt.  I agree about using accessors for primitive types, keeps things consistent.  Matt - I'm sorted now, just had a typo in my code!